# Using R language to generate an HTML page without escaping tags

Tags: javascript, html, r

Using tags$script i can generate <script> tags and execute the JavaScript within the page, by i don't know why < and > got escaped. 
Here's my R code:

```
require(shiny)
server <- function(input, output, session) {}
ui <- fluidPage(tags$script("document.write('Hello <br/> World!');"))
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: try wrapping the JS in HTML().. I.e. tags $script(HTML (....))

Comment: wrapping the js in HTML() din't work.  I wonder whether there is any else ideas?

Comment: try just creating a separate js file with just your javascript. then fluidPage (includeScript ("thefile.js")) I cant reproduce your issue nor do I understand why you couldn't just use tags $ div ("hello", tags $ br (),"world")

Comment: Thanks! I am new to shiny, you really helping me a lot! I make a stupid mistake when i use the first solution you provided so that makes the HTML() didn't work (I missed a back brace), and the second solution is also helpful!